# Some of my CSS doesn't work when switching to mobile view

Tags: css, responsive-design

I wonder why some part of my CSS codes does not work in mobile view.
See the attached image. I want to have these links (Speed Test) to the right with some spaces between the left text.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp778.png)

In desktop, it's ok (there is enough space) but when it goes to the mobile view all links stick to the left text.

Here is my **HTML** code:

```
<section class="server-section">
<div id="left-server">
<ul>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Las Vegas, NV</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Philadelphia, PA</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Los Angeles, CA</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Ashburn, VA</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Garden City, NY</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Chicago, IL</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="center-server">
<ul>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Dallas, TX</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Denver, CO</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Bend, OR</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Phoenix, AZ</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Seattle, WA</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Boston, MA</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/us.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Miami, FL</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="right-server">
<ul>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/ca.png" alt="Canada Flag" /> <span>Canada</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/se.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Sweden</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/de.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Germany</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/nl.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Netherlands</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/ch.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>Switzerland</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
<li><img src="images/icons/flags/uk.png" alt="USA Flag" /> <span>England</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</section>
```

And **CSS** code:

```
@media (min-width:961px) {
.server-section{
padding:50px 0px 300px;
height: 650px;
background-color:#f8fefa;
width:100%;
background-image:url("../images/resource/server-location.jpg");
}

.server-section ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

.server-section li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d1cb;
}

.server-section li span {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px;
color: #fff;
}

.server-section li a {
float: right;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
color: #00fc97;
padding-left: 20px;
}

.server-section li a:hover {
color: #fff;
}

.server-section li img {
margin-right: 20px;
}

.server-section #left-server {
float:left;
margin-left:35px; 
width: 30%;
}

.server-section #center-server {
float:left; 
width: 25%;
margin-left:50px;
}

.clear{
clear:both;
}

.server-section #right-server {
float:left;
margin-left:45px; 
width: 28%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media query that you have is smaller screens than `961px`, I think it is best to create a query for mobil

```
@media (max-width: 599px) {
   .server-section a{
      margin-left: 15px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `@media (min-width: 961px)` wrapping *all* of your CSS, which tells the web browser to only use that CSS when the width of the window is at least 960px. So when you switch to a smaller window (not mobile in particular), those styles disappear.

If you remove that, your formatting comes back, even on a narrow window.

Here's a sample, using a slightly-modified version of your code. If you view it in full screen and make your window less than 400 pixels wide, the green background will turn orange.

```css
.server-section {
  background-color: #ff9966; /* light orange */
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .server-section {
    background-color: #f8fefa; /* light green */
  }
}

/* After here, everything is from your code. */

.server-section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.server-section li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d1cb;
}

.server-section li span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.server-section li a {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  color: #00fc97;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.server-section li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="server-section">
  <div id="left-server">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Las Vegas, NV</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
      <li><span>Philadelphia, PA</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
      <li><span>Los Angeles, CA</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="center-server">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Dallas, TX</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
      <li><span>Denver, CO</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
      <li><span>Bend, OR</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right-server">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Canada</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
      <li><span>Sweden</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
      <li><span>Germany</span><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

As an aside, I can't speak for most people, but I'd much prefer to see `min-width: 960px` used as the cutoff for mobile websites (because that's exactly half of my monitor's width, and I like having two windows open at once).

Answer (score 0):

Try indentation

```
a{
text-indent:  5;
}
```

Comment: Generally, an answer should have a bit more explanation to it beyond just code - it needs to be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below outside of your @media query. Your media query is preventing any styles for screens smaller than 961px. You'll need to specify styles for smaller screens.

```
.server-section li span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```